# How to calculate minimum value in all variables? Python

Tags: python

I'm confused on how to make a function that calculate the minimum values from all variable

*for example*

```
>>>Myscore1 = 6 
>>>Myscore2 =-3
>>>Myscore3 = 10
```

the function will return the score and True if it is minimum value or else it is False . 
So from the above example the output will be:

```
>>>[(6,False),(-3,True),(10,False)]
```

Comment: Is there any reason your scores aren't in a list? Then you could just do `min(scores)`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yeah, it is an assignment and it is written not in a list.

Comment: -1 because you did't tried anything so far

Comment: I would insist that the scores are in a list. You could for instance first create an empty list, then append the list with new values as they come, i.e.: `Myscores = []; Myscores.append(6)` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply :

```
>>> scores = [Myscore1, Myscore2, Myscore3]
>>> [(x, (x == min(scores))) for x in scores]
[(6, False), (-3, True), (10, False)]
```

Comment: note: Be careful of using functions like `min` repeatedly when dealing with large data structures, it works fine here but can lead to O(N^2) behaviour

Comment: @jamylak : it is true. It would be nice, though, if a modern language were able to see that scores cannot change during this line, and therefore min(score) cannot change either.

Answer (score 4):

```
scores = [6, -3, 10]
def F(scores):
    min_score = min(scores)
    return [(x, x == min_score) for x in scores]

>>> F(scores)
[(6, False), (-3, True), (10, False)]
```

Answer (score 1):

A one liner using `enumerate`

```
scores = [6, -3, 10]

import operator
res = [[scores[i], True] 
   if i == min(enumerate(scores), key = operator.itemgetter(1))[0] 
   else [scores[i], False] 
   for i in range(len(scores))]
```